# laravel eloquent pivot with primary id to reference to another pivot

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot, many-to-many

i have problem with relationship between pivot tables.

I have many to many relation between countries and streets but primary key of this (pivot table) has many to many relationship with numbers.

I need this listings (with eloquent):

```
$country = Country::findOrFail(1)->with('streets', 'numbers')
foreach ($country->streets as $street){
    foreach($street->numbers as $number) {
       $number;
    }
}
```

Or exist any solution?

This is only example. Official name of tables are changed.

Example structure:

```
Table Countries
    id
    name

Table Streets
    id
    name

Table country_street
   id
   country_id
   street_id

Table number_country_street
   id
   number_id
   country_street_id

Table numbers
   id
   name
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: IMHO i think your pivot should be modeled, Try to add the model CountryStreet, relationships should become easier.

Comment: @dparoli can you give me model class CountryStreet with relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO with your tables I would define an additional model: CountryStreet, something like that:

```
// CountryStreet
class CountryStreet extends Model
{
    public function city()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
    }

    public function street()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Street');
    }
    public function numbers()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Number', 'number_country_street');
    }
}

// Country
class Country extends Model
{
    public function streets()
    {
         return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Street', 'App\CountryStreet');
    }
}

// Streets
class Street extends Model
{
    public function countries()
    {
         return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Country', 'App\CountryStreet');
    }
}

// Number
class Number extends Model
{
    public function country_streets()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\CountryStreet', 'number_country_street');
    }
}
```

Comment: class CountryStreet extend Model or Pivot becase is it pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

@dparoli had good idea.

Sometimes for many-to-many relations using inheritance Pivot class, but does not matter for now.

So now we can use these code bellow for listings.

```
$country = Country::findOrFail(1);
foreach ($country->countryStreet as $countryStreet){
    echo $countryStreet->street->name
    foreach($countryStreet->numbers as $number) {
       $number;
    }
}

class Countries
     public function countryStreet()
     {
         return $this->hasMany(CountryStreet::class, 'country_id', 'id');
     }

Class CountryStreet with method block() using relation hasOne
```

Another implementation is up.